# complex logarithm

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I have $e^{jk}$ and I want to take a logarithm from it, $\log(e^{jk})$ must be $jk$, right?
here some example I have tried to do with matlab.
$$\log(e^{j2})=j2$$
$$\log(e^{j3})=j3$$
but for $e^{j4}$ it gives me:  $\log(e^{j4})=-j2.2832$, why it doesn't give me $j4$
note: $\log$ is natural logarithm

Comment: Logarithms are only defined modulo $2\pi i$ ($2\pi j$ in electrical engineering notation). You got $(4-2\pi)j$, since whatever you used normalised the argument between $-\pi$ and $\pi$.

Comment: so you are saying that $log(e^{jk})$ is $j(k-2\pi)$? @DanielFischer

Comment: Worse, it's $(k + 2m\pi)j$ for any integer $m$.

Comment: but why for $log(e^{j2})=j2$ it gives me j2?@DanielFischer

Comment: Matlab seems to normalise the argument between $-\pi$ and $\pi$. Now, $2,3 < \pi$, but $4 > \pi$, so it normalises the argument $e^{4j} = e^{(4-2\pi)j}$, and now $-\pi < 4-2\pi < \pi$, so it's happy and tells you the normalised argument.

Comment: very useful , thanks @DanielFischer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

Since $e^{i\theta} = e^{i(\theta+2n\pi)}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, it doesn't have a well-defined inverse. That is, to define 'the' complex logarithm we need to restrict the domain of $z \mapsto e^z$. There's no single 'correct' way of doing this, so it amounts to choosing a 'branch' of the logarithm.

In general,
$$\log(z) = \log|z| + i\arg(z)$$
for some choice of range of $\arg(z)$. (For a given $z$, $\arg(z)$ is only well-defined up to adding some integer multiple of $2\pi$.)

Notice that $−2.283184\dots = 4 - 2\pi$.

The long and short of it is: $\log z$ might take many different values, depending on the choice of branch implicit in writing '$\log$'. Yours may differ from MATLAB's.