# Prove $e^i=i^{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ true or false?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Assume $~e^{i~x}=\cos(x)~+~i~\sin(x)~$ is questionable, can't be used.

Comment: Raise both sides to the power of pi - which leaves you with $e^{ipi} =i^2 (or - 1)$

Comment: I assumed you got this equation by manipulating $ e^{i \pi} = -1 = i^2 $. The answer is no, see [Complex logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [complex logarithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578477/complex-logarithm)

Comment: What have you tried, what are you given?

Comment: In my test (assuming 1/∞≠0)

Comment: Just try it, I'm a newbie.  Let sin(x)=∑(n=0,∞){ (i^(2*n))*(x^(2*n+1))/((2*n)+1)! }
     cos(x)=∑(n=0,∞){ (i^(2*n))*(x^(2*n))/(2*n)! }

 w(x)=cos(x)+i*sin(x)
  =∑(n=0,∞){ ((i^(2*n))*(x^(2*n)))/(2*n)! + i*(i^(2*n))*(x^(2*n+1))/(2*n+1)! }
  =∑(n=0,∞){ ((i*x)^(2*n))/(2*n)! +((i^(2*n)*x^(2*n))*(i*x))/((2n+1)*(2*n)!) }
  =∑(n=0,∞){ ((i*x)^(2*n))/(2*n)! +((i^(2*n)*x^(2*n))/(2*n)!)* ((i*x)/(2*n+1)) }
  =∑(n=0,∞){ ((i*x)^(2*n))/(2*n)! * (1+(i*x)/(2*n+1)) }

 Let e^x=∑(n=0,∞) {(x^n)/n!}
 <=> e^(i*x)=∑(n=0,∞) {((i*x)^n)/n!}

 ∴ equation e^(i*x)=cos(x)+i*sin(x) may be questionable or others

Comment: Sorry about the supplement. Easy fix: post it to an editor and realign by hand

Answer (score 3):

$e^i$, value of the exponential function, has one value, $\cos 1 + i \sin 1$.

But $i^{2/\pi}$ has many values, since that is how the complex exponent $u^v$ works.

$$
i^{2/\pi} = \exp\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\log(i)\right)
$$
and multi-valued $\log(i)$ has values
$$
\frac{\pi i}{2} + 2\pi k i,\qquad k \in \mathbb Z
$$
so $i^{2/\pi}$ has values
$$
\exp\left(\frac{2}{\pi}\;i\;\left(\frac{\pi + 2\pi k}{2}\right)\right)
=
\exp\left(i\;\left(1 + 2 k\right)\right)
=
\cos(1+2k) + i \sin(1+2k),\qquad k \in \mathbb Z
$$
Yes.  One of the values is, indeed, $e^i = \cos 1 + i \sin 1$.  But it is best not to say
$$
e^i = i^{2/\pi}
$$
because of the other values.

---

Suppose we interpret $e^i$ as a complex exponent.
Then it also has many values.
$$
\exp(i\log(e))
$$
and complex $\log(e)$ has values
$$
1+2\pi i k,\qquad k \in \mathbb Z
$$
so all values are
$$
\exp(i(1+2\pi i k)) = \exp(i-2\pi k) =
e^{-2\pi k}\big(\cos 1 + i \sin 1\big)
$$
All values of $e^i$ except one are *different* from values of $i^{2/\pi}$.
Indeed, the values of $i^{2/\pi}$ all have modulus $1$, while the values of $e^i$ have modulus $e^{-2\pi k}$, and these are all $\ne 1$ except for the one value with $k=0$.

Comment: You got it backward. e^i is multi-valued. i^(2/π) is a pure complex number

Comment: @ijwwij: what you said is incorrect. You should check your definition of $e^i$.